# How to inject csrf token into request before POSTing from a python function?

Tags: python, django, django-csrf

I am doing a POST request from a python function. Is there a helper to add csrf to the POST body?

I tried the csrf_protect decorator but that does not seem to work in this case. I think it works for a GET operation only.

Here is some code (not sure it has any detail not available above):

```
new_request = RequestFactory().post('/settings/', next_request)
new_request.session = request.session
user = User.objects.get(username=username)
user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
login(new_request, user)
new_request.user = user
return views.client_form(new_request)
```

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: Yeah, this doesn’t make sense.  Are you trying to call a django view from within django?  If so, you don’t have to fill in CSRF forms, you can just call that view directly in python.

Comment: When I post to the form (last line in my code snipper), I get a 403 - csrf_error. As part of form validation, I have to complete an Oauth2 flow and this happens on the way back.

Comment: It does make sense if this is for testing his functions.